# Match two regex patterns multiple times

Tags: python, regex, string

I have this string "Energy (kWh/m²)" and I want to get "Energy__KWh_m__", meaning, replacing all non word characters and sub/superscript characters with an underscore.

I have the regex for replacing the non word characters -> `re.sub("[\W]", "_", column_name)` and the regex for replacing the superscript numbers -> `re.sub("[²³¹⁰ⁱ⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁺⁻⁼⁽⁾ⁿ]", "", column_name)`

I have tried combining this into one single regex but I have had no luck. Every time I try I only get partial replacements like "Energy (KWh_m__" - with a regex like **([²³¹⁰ⁱ⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁺⁻⁼⁽⁾ⁿ]).*(\W)**

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: You say you want to replace the chars matched with an underscore, but you have `""` as the replacement for the `[²³¹⁰ⁱ⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁺⁻⁼⁽⁾ⁿ]` pattern, this is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your current code, if you plan to remove the superscript chars and replace all other non-word chars with an underscore, you can use

```py
re.sub(r'([²³¹⁰ⁱ⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁺⁻⁼⁽⁾ⁿ])|\W', lambda x: '' if x.group(1) else '_', text)
```

If you plan to match all the non-word chars and the chars in the character class you have, just merge the two:

```py
re.sub(r'[\W²³¹⁰ⁱ⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁺⁻⁼⁽⁾ⁿ]', '_', text)
```

See this second [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3ciYyO/1). Note that the `\W` matches the symbols, so you can even shorten this to `r'[\W²³¹⁰ⁱ⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹ⁿ]'`.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/T2Vz5P):

```py
import re
text="Energy (kWh/m²)"
print(re.sub(r'([²³¹⁰ⁱ⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁺⁻⁼⁽⁾ⁿ])|\W', lambda x: '' if x.group(1) else '_', text)) # => Energy__kWh_m_
print(re.sub(r'[\W²³¹⁰ⁱ⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁺⁻⁼⁽⁾ⁿ]', '_', text)) # => Energy__kWh_m__
```

Comment: This worked perfectly when I wrote the python code for it. I was testing the regex first on regex101.com and for some reason it doesn't match anything there. Not sure why there's the mismatch. Thanks!